# Visual Studio 11's graphics debugger crashing on capture in OMSetRenderTargets

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graphics, directx-11

We have two versions of the program, one which is a game and one which is the editor of which the same game.dll is used to render to a window. The game can create a Graphics Diagnostics capture with no problem. But in the editor during a capture we see this exception on calls to OMSetRenderTargets. The d3d11 calls are all the exact same, the only difference is that the device is rendering to a window created in the C# application rather than the C++ game. This only happens while a frame capture is in progress.

```
First-chance exception at 0x7626c42d in Editor.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0045dbb4.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the theory that std:bad_alloc had something to do with memory related to the render target. I played around with the size of the render target (a full level overlay in this case) and found that the Graphics Diagnostics capture cannot deal with render targets over 2048x2048. Looks like it was running out of memory.